# What does "out there" really mean here? And how common in spoken English? Does it have a fixed meaning all the time?

Tags: word-meaning

In this interview, we hear **out there** three times. At [00:35](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=9nb5TesrFDY&t=35s)  the women says : "finding my way of getting out there" , and she repeats somethings like that at [00:44](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=9nb5TesrFDY&t=44s)  and , [00:51](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=9nb5TesrFDY&t=51s). What do they mean? Do they mean different things?

Answer (score 2):

"Getting out there" is a colloquial expression that means  "to establish a reputation in a particular niche, market, domain, etc".

Budding actors speak of "getting their name out there" or of "getting out there". A CEO of a startup company might hire a publicist to "get the company's name out there"

Comment: I agree with this as the specific meaning in the video, but I think it's broader than that.  "Get out there" can be used for any figurative move from safety or seclusion to a more exposed position, socially, professionally, or romantically.  Ex: Joe hasn't dated since his wife left him; he really needs to get out there and meet a woman.   Jane is very shy; I think she'd be happier if she'd get out there and make some friends.  As a total aside, "out there" as opposed to "get out there" means eccentric, or crazy.  ex: Alan thinks that aliens are sending signs to humanity, he's really out there.

Comment: Good answer.  Maybe make it even better by adding a clarification between "get out there" and "out there" meaning "weird" or "off beat"

Comment: Point accepted, Jason. But "out there" meaning "crazy" is usually accompanied by an intensifier like "so" or "really" or "way". Kramer on Seinfeld might say "Oh, he's out there, Jerry. Way out."